# Invalid use of group function with MAX

Tags: php, mysql, forms

My code gives me the following error:

> Invalid use of group function

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT `text` FROM `text` WHERE `id`=max(id)");
   if(!$query)
die(mysql_error());
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
   echo $row['text'];
}
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Please. Stop using `mysql_query` in new code, it's a deprecated interface. You're just writing something that'll fail completely when those methods will be removed in future versions of PHP. [Switching to PDO is not hard](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and will provide a number of other benefits.

Answer (score 5):

If you want the row with highest id you could use:
`SELECT text FROM text ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1`

Answer (score 5):

`WHERE` clauses affect individual rows, whereas `HAVING` clauses affect aggregations (results of `GROUP BY` clauses).  Row criteria must be limited to the `WHERE` clause, aggregate functions (like MAX) must be used in `HAVING` clauses.

You could do this:

```
SELECT *

FROM   text

WHERE  id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM text);
```